# How to get attributes of columns from SQL query (PHP \ Phalcon \ PostgreSQL)

Tags: php, postgresql, phalcon

I have two tables: `manager`, `order`.

One manager has many orders.

How i can get columns types, which in SELECT, from query like this

```
SELECT m.name, o.date, o.phone
FROM manager m
LEFT JOIN order o ON m.id = o.manager_id
```

Comment: If you want to get this from php, please take a look from [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-field-type.php)

Comment: Thanks, but for pg_field_type() i must open a new connection to db. I try do like this:

`$sql = "SELECT m.name, o.date, o.phone
FROM manager m
LEFT JOIN order o ON m.id = o.manager_id";`

`$tableData = $this->db->prepare($sql);`

but `var_dump($tableData->getColumnMeta(0));` return `false`

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql 9.4

```
SELECT column_name , data_type ,character_maximum_length  FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema' AND table_name   = 'your_table';
```

Answer (score 0):

From Phalcon you can use Model metadata.

```
$manager = new Manager();
$order = new Order();

$metadata = $model->getModelsMetaData();

var_dump($metadata->getDataTypes($manager));
```

You will get and array with each column name and the type as an integer.

```
array (size=3)
  'col1' => int 0
  'col2' => int 2
  ...
  'coln' => int 2
```

The integer is one of the `TYPE_*` constants from `\Phalcon\Db\Column`.